# Number of Lines for UILabel not Updating as Expected When TableViewCell is Tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I am changing the `numberOfLines` attribute on a label that lives in a custom UITableViewCell when the cell is tapped.  However, this is not reflected in the UI until the second tap.  The cell is configured as a prototype cell in the table view to initially have 2 lines.

Interestingly enough, when I print out the `numberOfLines` value before and after my `tapped()` function runs, the values start off different, and then synchronize - after the first tap, I see 2 lines before the function runs, then 0 lines after the function runs.  However, after subsequent taps, I see the same value before and after my function, which makes it seem like it's not doing anything, even though the UI does stretch and shrink the cell, and the `numberOfLines` value is changed for the next time the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function runs.

I'm only seeing this behavior with `tableView.reloadRows()`.  If I do a full update with `tableView.reloadData()`, the cell appropriately grows and collapses the first time it is tapped.  However, this feels a bit ham-fisted and doesn't animate nicely like `reloadRows()` does.

TableView Implementation

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                       didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ReviewTableViewCell
             else { return }
         let data = tableData[indexPath.row]

         print("old number of lines: \(cell.detailLabel.numberOfLines)")

             //data.isOpen is set to false initially
             cell.tapped(data.isOpen)
         tableData[indexPath.row].isOpen = !data.isOpen
             tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

             print("old number of lines: \(cell.detailLabel.numberOfLines)")


//      tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Custom Table View Cell method

```
    func tapped(_ isOpen: Bool) {
         if !isOpen {
              detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0     }
         else {
          detailLabel.numberOfLines = 2     }
    }
```

I am expecting this code to expand the cell once it is reloaded with `tableView.reloadRows()` if the `numberOfLines` is set to 0 and collapse the cell when it is set to 2.  This does work, but only after tapping the cell two+ times.  This should work with the first tap as well.

Here is a link of a gif that shows the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoZId.jpg

Here is a sample project that is similar to what's going on in my app: https://github.com/imattice/CellLabelExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work out what was going on.  The problem is in two parts.

The first part is calling `reloadRows()`.  This method is swapping out the cells with a new cell rather than updating the cell that already exists.  Therefore, I'm changing the number of lines on that hidden swap cell rather than the cell that is in view.  This behavior is mentioned in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows):

> Reloading a row causes the table view to ask its data source for a new cell for that row. The table animates that new cell in as it animates the old row out.

Additionally, I'm using structs as the data model for tracking the open status of the cell.  In Swift, structs are copy-on-write, which means that if a value is changed on that struct, a new struct is created rather than changing the value of that struct I'm pointing to.  This means the line `tableData[indexPath.row].isOpen = !data.isOpen` doesn't do anything useful - we look at the tableData struct at the index path, get it's `isOpen` value, copy a new struct and change that new struct's `isOpen` value, and then throw it out because the new struct is not assigned anywhere.

The solution is to not use the `reloadRows()` method and to either use 
A) a `class` for the data object
B) replace the data at indexPath.row to the copied struct

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell else { return }
        var data = tableData[indexPath.row]

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        cell.tapped(isOpen: data.isOpen)
        data.isOpen = !data.isOpen

        tableData[indexPath.row] = data
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, to get this trick work `UILabel` generally must be constrained on each side to it's superview, in this way when it changes its `intrinsicContentSize` is able to push each side to accomodate the text.
Saying that, try to wrap the tapped method with those two methods:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
if !isOpen {
    detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0     
}
else {
    detailLabel.numberOfLines = 2     
}
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Of course tableview must be set to automatic size:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = <#What you want#>
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!  I can confirm that I've got my constraints implemented and the row height is set to automatic.  I've also tried the `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` around the `tapped` method in `tableView:didSelectRowAt`, but I'm still seeing the same behavior:  the first tap flashes the cell and appears to update content, and the second tap stretches the cell as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't implemented any of the "height" delegate methods? if you did try comment them

Comment: Check this sample code I've found on github https://github.com/rayfix/MultilineDemo/blob/master/MultilineDemo/MultilineTableVC.swift

Comment: I've updated the question to show a gif of the issue in the UI, as well as a sample project on my github that shows how my cells are set up and how it behaves once built.